# How to send email with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, smtp

I'd like to send email from PowerShell,
so I use this command:

```
$EmailFrom = "customer@yahoo.com"
$EmailTo = "receiver@ymail.com"  
$Subject = "today date"
$Body = "TODAY SYSTEM DATE=01/04/2016  SYSTEM TIME=11:32:05.50"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)   
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true    
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("customer@yahoo.com", "password")    
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

This command didn't work for Yahoo mail or Outlook mail, but works for my Gmail.
Is there anything wrong that I have done?

Comment: Any reason not to [use `Send-MailMessage`?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36343788/712649)

Comment: I am just learning PS, i didnt know that command is exist

Comment: Just want to note that Send-MailMessage is now deprecated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The following code snippet for sending SMTP e-mail through Gmail works for me:

```
$Username = "MyUserName";
$Password = "MyPassword";
$path = "C:\attachment.txt";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "YourName@gmail.com";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "subject text here...";
    $message.Body = "body text here...";
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment);

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", "587");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
    $attachment.Dispose();
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email "reciever@gmail.com" -attachmentpath $path;
```

Comment: By the way, you need to allow access for less secure apps in your gmail account settings. It works with gmail at least.

Comment: Hi, Im trying to use Sean's solution in a email.ps1 file and running it from the command line with this PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\email.ps1 but I keep getting an error about authentication.  I'm using the correct password, for the username I tried my gmail user name with @gmail.com and without. Hope you can help

Comment: How do I add more than 1 attachment?

Answer (score 12):

I use this:

```
Send-MailMessage -To hi@abc.com -from hi2@abc.com -Subject 'hi' -SmtpServer 10.1.1.1
```

Comment: How could you set a specific time for it , example using the code above - send an email at 4:00 pm for example

Comment: FYI this command is obsolete because it cannot guarantee secure connections. See this page for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you may need to set the EnableSsl to false (in this case the message will be sent unencrypted over the network)

Comment: the parameter does note exist

Comment: Well it worked for me.  That's why I wrote this.  If none of these solutions work for you find another article.

Comment: Context is everything, for this is a valid answer, as shown here: [SMTPClient Failure During Send Concerning Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57667604/285795).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Gmail smtp.

Following is The powershell code to send a gmail message with an Attachment:

```
    $Message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage 
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587) 
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("From@gmail.com", "password"); 
    $smtp.EnableSsl = $true 
    $smtp.Timeout = 400000  
    $Message.From = "From@gmail.com" 
    $Message.To.Add("To@gmail.com") 
    $Message.Attachments.Add("C:\foo\attach.txt") 
    $smtp.Send($Message)
```

On the sender Google Account (From@gmail.com),

Make sure you have Turned ON Access for less-secure apps option,
from google Account Security Dashboard.

Finally, Save this Script As mail.ps1

To invoke the above Script Simple run below on Command Prompt or batch file:

```
    Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File mail.ps1
```

By Default, For sending Large Attachments Timeout is Around 100 seconds or so.
In this script, it is increased to Around 5 or 6 minutes

Comment: how is this more secure than `Send-MailMessage`?