# Azure DevOps - send email notification after test results have been published

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

We have a nightly scheduled pipeline that runs tests and publishes the results to a test run. We can see the the url to the test run as this is generated by the PublishTestResults@2 task. I'd like to extend this functionality by emailing a set of users the devops link to the test run.

Here's how the publish task currently looks:

```
steps:
  # Publish test results (to show the test details in JUnit format)
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: 'Publish test results'
    inputs:
      testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
      testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
      searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cypress/reports/junit'
      mergeTestResults: true
      testRunTitle: 'Publish Test Results'
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    continueOnError: true
```

Are there any recommended approaches to doing this?

Comment: Have you looked into notifications? That might be a simple approach if you don't need super granular configuration options, you can for example send an email on completion of certain builds: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications

Comment: Hi @danielorn, yip I have looked into notifications, but I don't know how I can capture the url for the test run.  To me using notifications is a bit 'late' in the process which was why I was thinking of an additional step inside the pipeline.  I'll read up on the link you sent me, you never know, perhaps I could find something useful there - thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand, with the requirement of sending a link to the url for the test the notifications are probably not gonna cut it, what you will get is typically a link to the pipeline run itself. To have full control you are better off adding a task in the pipeline that ends the email.

Comment: @dubs Is there any update about this ticket? if the answer could solve this issue, you can consider accepting it as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1: Notifications

If you just need a link to the pipeline run itself, you can configure a [notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops).

## Option 2: Email Report Extension

If you want more control than notifications offer the [Email Report Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=epsteam.EmailReportExtension) from Microsoft DevLabs generates (a customizable) report sent to a list of recipients that contains:

> - **Overall Test Summary** : This info mirrors the Test Tab in the Pipeline.
> - **Test Run Summary**: Information about individual test runs happened in
>   the Pipeline if any.
> - **Test Failures**: Shows Test Failures, their stack traces (Configurable
>   in the Task Input) and associated workitems.
> - Commits/Changeset Information
> - Phases/Environments Information
> - Task information: Task(s) that ran in the pipeline - Name, Duration
>   and any error logs if failed.

You will need to provide credentials for the smtp server the email should be sent through

## Option 3: Other extension

There is [a number of 3rd party email sending extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=email&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) for Azure DevOps,

## Option 4: Custom script

There is of course also the option to create a bash/powershell script to send the email, here is a simple Powershell Example: [How to send email with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355271/how-to-send-email-with-powershell)

Comment: Option 2 - be aware that this extension has many bugs and support for this extension basically does not exist (looking at https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-engineering-extensions/issues). Also I am experiencing bug - it sends emails to random people from my organization (which are however closely related to me in example from my internal team)