# PowerShell script to monitor a log and output progress to another

Tags: powershell, logging, text, monitoring

I have a PowerShell script to upgrade our Windows 10 computers to newer feature updates. The script also logs certain steps as they progress so we can track them. However, the actual upgrade step takes a couple of hours and (currently) there's no visibility on how far along it is until it's finished. Here's what I have so far:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log" -Tail 0 -Wait | Where {$_ -Match "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[10%]"}
Add-Content -Path "\\SERVER1\Logs\Upgrade.log" -Value "Upgrade stage is at 10% progress"
Get-Content -Path "C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log" -Tail 0 -Wait | Where {$_ -Match "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[20%]"}
Add-Content -Path "\\SERVER1\Logs\Upgrade.log" -Value "Upgrade stage is at 20% progress"
```

This works, in so far as Upgrade.log is updated when the script sees the "Mapped Global Progress: 10%" value appear in setupact.log, but the problem is it stops there and will not detect any further updates. I assume this is because of the `-wait` parameter added to the `Get-Content` command.

Does anyone know of a way (within PowerShell as I'd prefer not to use an external program) of monitoring the log as described but not experiencing the pause after the first match?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do it with a .NET class written in C#.  It uses a class called LogFileMonitor which we first define using `Add-Type`.

Once the type is loaded we can then create an instance of it.  It's constructor takes in the path to the log that will be monitored and a TimeSpan for defining how often we want to check for updates in the log.  In the code below it is set to every second.

Next we subscribe to one of the 2 available events: LineAdded or LinesAdded. I've chosen to go with LinesAdded which will raise only 1 event every second (or whatever our chosen timespan was) and return a list of lines containing all of the lines that have been added since the last check. We will check these individually in our action.
(The other, LineAdded, will raise 1 event for every new line that is added and provide the single line.  If 10 lines are added in the last second, 10 events will be raised each with 1 line.  )

When subscribing we need to define the action we would like to perform when the event we are subscribing to is raised.  This is where we check the line for a match and update the other log.  I've decided to use a switch here with the -regex option.  When any of our lines match one of the regex patterns we've listed then the scriptblock will be executed adding content to the other log (or whatever other action we define)

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CustomClasses
{
    public class LogFileMonitor
    {
        private DateTime _lastWriteTime;

        private int _lineCount;
        private TimeSpan _checkInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

        public string Path { get; }
        public bool Active { get; private set; } = false;

        public LogFileMonitor(string path)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
            }

            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not find file", path);
            }

            Path = path;
            _lastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
            _lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
        }

        public LogFileMonitor(string path, TimeSpan interval) : this(path)
        {
            _checkInterval = interval;
        }

        public event EventHandler<LineAddedEventArgs> LineAdded;
        public event EventHandler<LinesAddedEventArgs> LinesAdded;

        protected virtual void OnLineAdded(LineAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<LineAddedEventArgs> handler = LineAdded;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnLinesAdded(LinesAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<LinesAddedEventArgs> handler = LinesAdded;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        public virtual async Task StartMonitoring()
        {
            if (!Active)
            {
                Active = true;

                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    do
                    {
                        DateTime currentLastWriteTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(Path);
                        if (_lastWriteTime != currentLastWriteTime)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
                                _lastWriteTime = currentLastWriteTime;

                                if (lines.Length > _lineCount)
                                {
                                    var linesAddedArgs = new LinesAddedEventArgs()
                                    {
                                        Lines = lines.Skip(_lineCount).ToList<string>()
                                    };
                                    OnLinesAdded(linesAddedArgs);

                                    int newLineNumber = 0;
                                    foreach (string line in lines.Skip(_lineCount))
                                    {
                                        var lineAddedArgs = new LineAddedEventArgs()
                                        {
                                            Line = line,
                                            LineNumber = _lineCount + ++newLineNumber
                                        };
                                        OnLineAdded(lineAddedArgs);
                                    }
                                    _lineCount = lines.Length;
                                }
                                else if (lines.Length < _lineCount)
                                {
                                    _lineCount = lines.Length;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (IOException)
                            {
                                // Log file likely being written to
                            }
                        }
                        Task.Delay((int)_checkInterval.TotalMilliseconds).Wait();
                    } while (Active);
                });

                Active = false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Monitoring is already active.  Subscribe to 'LineAdded' Event.");
            }
        }

        public virtual void StopMonitoring()
        {
            Active = false;
        }
    }
}

public class LineAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int LineNumber { get; set; }
    public string Line { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; } = DateTime.Now;
}

public class LinesAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public List<string> Lines { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; } = DateTime.Now;
}
'@

$logBeingMonitored = 'C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log'
$monitor = New-Object CustomClasses.LogFileMonitor -ArgumentList @($logBeingMonitored, [timespan]::new(0, 0, 1))

$subscriber = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $monitor -EventName LinesAdded -SourceIdentifier MyScript -Action {
    $logProgress = '\\SERVER1\Logs\Upgrade.log'
    switch -regex ($eventargs.lines) {
        'Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[10%]' { 
            Add-Content -Path $logProgress -Value 'Upgrade stage is at 10% progress'
        }
        'Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[20%]' {
            Add-Content -Path $logProgress -Value 'Upgrade stage is at 20% progress'
        }
        Default {}
    } 
}

$task = $monitor.StartMonitoring()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without use of a custom .NET class and to use `Get-Content -Wait` the way that you are using it is to run `Get-Content -Wait` in a job where it will not block the main thread and use `New-Event` to create an event that we can react to whenever `Get-Content` discovers a new line.

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier 'LoggingEventHandler' -Action {
    $logProgress = 'c:\temp\Upgrade.log'
    switch -regex ($event.messagedata) {
        'Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[10%]' {
            'Upgrade stage is at 10% progress' | Out-Host
            Add-Content -Path $logProgress -Value 'Upgrade stage is at 10% progress'
        }
        'Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[20%]' {
            'Upgrade stage is at 20% progress' | Out-Host
            Add-Content -Path $logProgress -Value 'Upgrade stage is at 20% progress'
        }

        Default {}
    }
}

Start-Job -Name 'Monitor Log' -ScriptBlock {
    Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier 'LoggingEventHandler' -Forward
    Get-Content -Path C:\temp\log.log -Wait | ForEach-Object { New-Event -SourceIdentifier 'LoggingEventHandler' -MessageData $_ }
}
```

Comment: Great work, Daniel. I really appreciate the effort you've put in for me. I think I'll try your second solution first as it's less actual code. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've tried the second method but it doesn't seem to be working 100%. If I may, I'll share my findings:

On first run, the script does not output anything, but on subsequent runs, it does.
When I type "exit", it outputs "Upgrade stage is at 10% progress" again before closing the PowerShell window.
It only produces output to the screen, not the log file (I have confirmed the path is correct)
It does not pause as I'd hoped after finding the first match (10%)

If you have some spare time, I'd really appreciate if you could please help me work through these bugs?

Thanks again.

Comment: Update, the second output of  "Upgrade stage is at 10% progress" happens even if I press <ENTER> so the "exit" command may be a red herring. It *seems* to be 'waiting' but not... if you know what I mean? I would expect that the PS command prompt would not return until the script had fully terminated?

Comment: All will run completely in the background.  As soon as you run the script you will be given back the PS prompt.  Start-Job will begin monitoring the log in the background.  Everything in the Register-EngineEvent action is also running as a job in the background.  As long as you keep the powershell window open it will continue to run.   If you just leave the window open, run your upgrade script, you should just see the the messages appear in the terminal as they are encountered in the log.

Comment: Ideally the upgrade script should be run in a different powershell session so that the console that you've started the monitoring script in is left free to only show you the status messages, however it should be entirely possible for you to run the update script from the same powershell console and still have the message appear mixed in.  As for 2nd upgrade log file not being updated, I'm not sure why this is the case.  The code works as.  I've tested both in powershell version 5.1 and 7 and it runs as expected: 2nd log is updated and message is outputted to screen.

Comment: HI Daniel, I was hoping you'd had a chance to look at my testing methodology (see below) and see if I was doing anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @JAG, sorry again.  As I mentioned in my other comment we have to move the assignment of the `$logProgress` variable into the Action block of the event handler.  Not sure why, but the previous code worked fine for me when running from VSCode as I often do.  I did not notice the issue until I ran the script directly from a powershell window...

Comment: Hi Daniel, when you have some spare time, I'd really appreciate it you could please help me figure out why the script only progresses after I have hit ENTER? Thanks.

Comment: Another good question...  I was also able to replicate this behavior.  It seems to only happen in PS v5.1.  Works as expected in PS 7+ which is what I tested in.  I'm not sure why this is happening.  I'll see if I can find an answer somewhere.  Maybe in the meantime you can try this more simplistic approach instead which is close to what you were originally going for https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971230/11954025

Comment: OK thanks Daniel (good find by the way!) I'll try that shortly and if it works, I'll reply here so you don't spend any unnecessary time on it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, as promised I gave it a try, but if you see the 'answer' I posted (only way to get the code formatted correctly) hopefully you'll see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Get-Content C:\temp\Test.log -Wait -Last 0 |
    ForEach-Object {
        switch -regex ($_) {
            '\[(\d+)%\]' {
                $match = $Matches[1]
                Write-Host "$match% Progress"
            }
            Default {  } # do nothing if line not matched
        }
    }
```

*Based off of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67971230/11954025)*

Comment: I really overcomplicated things with my other answers didn't I?.    I'm sincerely sorry about that

Comment: Hi Dan, no need to apologise, you've been extremely helpful and patient and I really appreciate that. I have almost got it, but I can't get the ForEach loop to break once it reaches 100% - I think the Break command may just be in the wrong place? See the code in my latest answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I must be doing something wrong because I can't get it to work. This is how I'm testing it, perhaps that will clarify things? By the way, this is using your second script exactly as is, without any mods.

1. I create a blank file called log.log in C:\temp
2. I open a PowerShell window as a standard user and cd \temp
3. I run Test.ps1 (your script) and the screen outputs the following:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
1      LoggingEvent...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
2      Monitor Log     BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...

PS C:\temp>
```

4. I edit C:\temp\log.log and add the following line to it:

```
2021-07-22 13:42:10, Info                  MOUPG  Mapped Global progress: [10%]
```

5. No output to the PowerShell window.
6. I then save the file, but still no output.
7. If I hit ENTER in the PowerShell window, I get the following output:

```
Upgrade stage is at 10% progress
```

8. I add the following line to C:\temp\log.log:

```
2021-07-22 13:42:10, Info                  MOUPG  Mapped Global progress: [20%]
```

9. I get no output.
10. If I save it, no output.
11. If I hit ENTER in PowerShell window, no output.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Oh my, I'm very sorry.  I found the issue.  Strange that it was working for me perfectly running the script from VSCode...  So the problem is that the variable `$logProcess` could not be accessed from within the -Action block so an error was being thrown when trying to write to the log which stopped any further processing of events.  What I've done to fix this is move the definition of $logProgress into the action which should resolve the issue for you too.  I've updated my answer to show this change.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the update. That has improved things a lot and the output is now as expected. There's just one thing: The output doesn't occur until I hit ENTER in the PowerShell window, so are we sure this will run fully automated?

Answer (score 0):

This is updated code extrapolated from your latest answer:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\Test.log -Wait -Last 0 |
ForEach-Object {
    Switch -RegEx ($_)
    {
        Default {}
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[10%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 10% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[20%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 20% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[30%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 30% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[40%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 40% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[50%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 50% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[60%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 60% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[70%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 70% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[80%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 80% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[90%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 90% progress"
        }
        "Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[100%]"
        {
            Write-Host "Upgrade stage is at 100% progress"
            Break
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have put a `Break` command after the upgrade stage is at 100% but it does not stop the loop processing. Do I need to place it elsewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: Almost there :)  So a `break` statement inside a switch just ends processing objects in the switch however we are only sending one object at a time so it really does nothing in this situation.  The break has to occur outside the switch in the foreach-object process block.  You can remove the break from where you have it now and add this line just after the end of the switch block `if ($_ -match 'Mapped\ Global\ progress:\ \[100%]') {break}`

Comment: YESSSS!!! That worked. Thanks ever so much for your patience and persistence, Daniel. I'd give you a thousand upvotes if I could. I owe you one...

Comment: Happy to hear it.  I learned a thing or two from this exchange as well so a big thank you too!