# Attach a file (or data) from Azure Pipeline directly to a Microsoft Teams channel?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I was going to try to [use email to send an artifact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36355678/1187583) from my Azure Pipeline but then thought, why not use MS Teams that we are already using!

But I can't find any tasks on the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=teams&target=AzureDevOps&category=Azure%20Pipelines&sortBy=Relevance) or examples on how to "hook" into it. Just to be clear I'm **not** looking for [notification and alerts on work items, PR etc.](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/)

So has anybody done this (or similar)?

Comment: Are you using Azure Data Factory Pipeline to send notification to Teams channel?, If yes, you can try with below:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/send-notification-on-a-microsoft-teams-channel-from-a-data/ba-p/2456636

If not, could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Sorry but I´m not able to test this until next week but I am not using ADFP but just normal Azure DevOps pipelinse and I´m in the process of implemented this by using SendGrid task to send the content of the artifact file in the body of the email. But if you can do this with ADFP we might be able to with DevOps, correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible.

Comment: We decided to send email from devops task instead. We might look into this later and then I´ll update this question