# Smtp server errors while sending email in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

The PowerShell email functionality is as below:

```
    $Attachment = "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Tools\Email_on_failure\errorlist.txt"
    $Subject = "Errors!"
    $Body = "See attachment"
    $SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
    $SMTPPort = "465"
    Send-MailMessage -From gs4u@yahoo.com -to gs4u@outlook.com -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) -Attachments $Attachment
```

But I receive this error below:

```
Send-MailMessage : Smtp server returned an invalid response.
At C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Tools\Email_on_failure\EOF.ps1:28 char:2
+     Send-MailMessage -From gowthamsaarthy4u@yahoo.com -to gowthamsaar ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

That too! The processing time for this was ~20 seconds. Please help!

Comment: In your example, it looks like you're missing the closing parentheses around `Get-Credential`

Comment: @derekbaker783 Hi. Actually it does have a close bracket. I missed while writing the query. Thanks for informing. Updated the question now with bracket. Please help me out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email from yahoo SMTP server with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342884/how-to-send-an-email-from-yahoo-smtp-server-with-powershell)

Comment: Try without the attachment and see if that works

Comment: `$SMTPPort` should be of type int. Remove the quotes there.

Comment: @Jawad I tried without attachment in my code. It failed with same previous error

Comment: @Theo I have removed quotes there but still same error comes.

Comment: Hey! Folks who tried to help me. Thanks. I found the solution. Let me test for some rounds & then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

(Working solution as of 2020)

If you wish to send emails from PowerShell using SMTP settings of prominent providers like gmail, yahoo & outlook, You need to do the below things first (I had used gmail for now. One can research and do similar below steps for yahoo or outlook too):

1. You need to turn off [2step](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification) authentication for your gmail account.
2. Then you need to turn on [LessSecureApp](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) access.

Now use the below code to send email from PowerShell (version of PS used is V5) code to trigger email:

```
    $Attachment = "C:\abc\def\errorlist.txt"
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'd*@*@*@*@*@*@*0' -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('gohy4u@gmail.com', $password)
    Send-MailMessage -From gohy4u@gmail.com -to g4u@gmail.com -Subject 'Subject line here' -Body 'Body line goes here' -SmtpServer 'smtp.gmail.com' -port 587 -UseSsl -Credential $credential -Attachments $Attachment
```

I had fed in credentials using $credentials tag as I use this code in some automation which shouldn't involve interruptions. One can use (Get-Credentials) as argument at -Credential for more safer way to feed credentials but it will interrupt by showing feed credentials pop-up window during the execution of script.